# Regressing a WN variable on a random walk

Tags: regression, time-series

I probably have a silly question, but what would the residuals look like if you regress a white noise variable on a random walk? I mainly refer to the order of integration of the residuals.
Would it be a spurious regression? Then, in this case, should the residuals be I(1)?
Thank you in advance.